# Rename a label on Github with curl

Tags: rest, github, label, github-api

I'm trying to rename a label on Github with the REST API. I can read the label

```sh
curl https://api.github.com/repos/adamschmideg/label-cleanup/labels/question
```

and it returns a nice json.

However when I try to update it following the doc on [Updating a Github issue label](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/labels/#update-a-label) and execute this

```sh
curl \
    --request PATCH \
    https://api.github.com/repos/adamschmideg/label-cleanup/labels/question \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --header "Accept: application/json" \
    --data "{\"name\": \"just-a-question\"}"
```

it returns a message "Not found". It returns the same message for a non-existant label.

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a [public repository](https://github.com/adamschmideg/label-cleanup) which means anybody can see its labels.

However, updating a label is restricted. You need to [authenticate](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication), e.g. by adding `-u "username"` to your request for basic authentication:

```sh
curl \
    -u "adamschmideg" \  # <-- Right here
    --request PATCH \
    https://api.github.com/repos/adamschmideg/label-cleanup/labels/question \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --header "Accept: application/json" \
    --data "{\"name\": \"just-a-question\"}"
```

If you're using two-factor authentication and you want to use basic authentication as shown here you'll need to [include a one-time code in a special `X-GitHub-OTP` header as well](https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/#working-with-two-factor-authentication).

GitHub also supports OAuth2 tokens sent in headers, or as URL parameters, which shouldn't require any special steps and are recommended if you're using 2FA.

[The reason](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication) you're getting "Not found" instead of something like "Please authenticate" is that

> Requests that require authentication will return `404 Not Found`, instead of `403 Forbidden`, in some places. This is to prevent the accidental leakage of private repositories to unauthorized users.